# ImageButton is not dragging and drawn

Tags: android

In my problem I am moving an image button onTouch event and the place where dragging stops redraw an image button at that place. Actually this is working perfectly for simple button but not with image button.

```
public class NActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private final static int START_DRAGGING = 0;
    private final static int STOP_DRAGGING = 1;

    private ImageButton btn;
    private FrameLayout layout;
    private int status;
    private LayoutParams params;
    private ImageView image;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        // layout.setOnTouchListener(this);

        btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(this);

        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            status = START_DRAGGING;
            image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageBitmap(btn.getDrawingCache());
            layout.addView(image, params);
        }
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            status = STOP_DRAGGING;
            Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
        } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
                System.out.println("Dragging");
                image.setPadding((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), 0, 0);
                image.invalidate();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to accept the best answers to your previous questions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example I have used a layout and put and *ImageButton* inside it, so that image button will inherit the properties of the layout it is inside
xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testing" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

java:

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private LinearLayout ll1;
    private FrameLayout layout;

    private float xAxis = 0;
    private float yAxis = 0;

    private LinearLayout newLinearLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);

        ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        newLinearLayout = ll1;

        ll1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void redraw() {
        layout.removeAllViews();

        newLinearLayout.setPadding((int) xAxis, (int) yAxis, 0, 0);

        layout.addView(newLinearLayout);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            xAxis = event.getX();
            yAxis = event.getY();
            redraw();

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            System.out.println("intermediate finished");

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is very simple and easy and in the end it does not matter which component is inside of the *LinearLayout* because this component does not matter

Comment: Ok i understood your point but then also its not working.The imagebutton getting is neither getting moved leave the point of redrawing